# Custom object-detection AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'app'

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, object-detection

I am doing [this project](https://pythonprogramming.net/creating-tfrecord-files-tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial/) on custom object-detection using tensorflow.

When I tried to create TF record for the train images using the following command:

```
python generate_tfrecord.py 
  --csv_input=images\train_labels.csv 
  --image_dir=images\train 
  --output_path=train.record
```

I get the following error:

> "generate_tfrecord.py", line 102, in tf.app.run()
>   AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'app'

What's going wrong?

Comment: Can we see the code you're using?

Answer (score 1):

Well I encountered the same issue,

You can resolve the same by making changes in generate_tfrecords.py file

Line 45:  Replace tf.gfile.GFile(os.path.join(path, '{}'.format(group.filename)), 'rb') as fid:
as
**tftf.compat.v1.gfile.GFile(os.path.join(path, '{}'.format(group.filename)), 'rb') as fid:**

Line 23: flags = tf.app.flags as **tf.compat.v1.flags**
Line 86:  writer =   writer = tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter(FLAGS.output_path) as t**f.compat.v1.python_io.TFRecordWriter(FLAGS.output_path)**
and
Line 100: tf.app.run() as **tf.compat.v1.app.run()**

Basically there are certain methods which are built according to Tensorflow Version 1.0 so for these you can use **tf.compat.v1** so that your code is modified for these particular methods which were throwing the errors.